# why error in arduino but in atmega8 proteus does not matter

Tags: c++11

```
wiring.c.o (symbol from plugin): In function `__vector_9':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_9'
C:\Users\syste\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\6F366EA3D470A87D93EB4DC2BC21772D\sketch\87segmentupdown.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
```

Compilation error: exit status 1

Please help me, I hope it can be resolved quickly heheh